# Implementing api client with multiple base urls

Tags: php, oop, soap, client

I need to build a client for soap api that has a separate base url for `get` and `post` http methods.

There are two separate WSDLs: one lists actions to read data and another one to insert data, for example: `https://www.example.com/webservices3/ExampleWS.asmx` and `https://www.example.com/webservices3/ExampleWSPost.asmx`.

How do I implement the client with multiple base urls?

Normally, with a single base url, I'd do something like this:

```php
use SoapClient;

class ExampleApiClient
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new SoapClient('example.com/path?wsdl');
    }

    public function getUser($args)
    {
        return $this->client->soapCall('exampleAction', $args);
    }

    public function addUser($args)
    {
        return $this->client->soapCall('exampleAction', $args);
    }
}

// which then will be called somewhere in the code like this:

$api = new ExampleApiClient();
$api->getUser(12);
```

Comment: What does the `Client` class do?

Comment: Are you meaning a separate domain or just a different path on the same domain?

Comment: @Rylee different path on the same doaim

Comment: @ADyson it's a php SoapClient, it sends and receives data. Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: I see. Surely the WSDL specifies the URL for each endpoint so you don't have to? Or are you saying there are two separate WSDLs you need to read from?

Comment: yes, there are two separate WSDLs, one lists actions to read data and another one to insert data, for example: `https://www.example.com/webservices3/ExampleWS.asmx` and `https://www.example.com/webservices3/ExampleWSPost.asmx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways to do this, but one way is to simply maintain two `SoapClient` instances in your class, and use each one as appropriate within the individual functions.

For example:

```
use SoapClient;

class ExampleApiClient
{
    protected $getClient;
    protected $postClient;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getClient = new SoapClient('example.com/path?wsdl');
        $this->postClient = new SoapClient('example.com/path2?wsdl');
    }

    public function getUser($args)
    {
        return $this->getClient->soapCall('exampleAction', $args);
    }

    public function addUser($args)
    {
        return $this->postClient->soapCall('exampleAction', $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've upvoted your answer. Before I accept it, let me consider some things. Will there be any downsides if I move the client instantiations into their own methods, like `public function getClient() { return new SoapClient('get_url'); }` and then make requests like this `$this->getClient()->soapCall('...')`?

Comment: Well that would create a new instance of SoapClient every time you make a request, which seems a bit wasteful. Why do that when you can create it once and re-use it?